# Генератор случайных простых математических примеров

Tags: python

товарищи! Написал функцию для генерации случайных чисел, не пойму как мне сделать проверку, чтобы одно число делилось на другое без остатка, вот пример кода...
Идея такая чтобы при делении operand3 на operand4 получалось целое число

```
    import random

import ast
 
def generate_equation():
    
    # Генерация случайных чисел для уравнения
    for i in range(20):
        operand1 = random.randint(1, 81)
        operand2 = random.randint(1, 19)
        operand3 = random.randint(1, 81)
        operand4 = operand3 // operand2
        operator = random.choice(['+', '-'])
        operator2 = random.choice(['*', '/'])
        operator3 = random.choice(['+', '-'])
        #operand5 = random.choice([])
        yield  operand1, operand2, operand3, operand4, operator, operator2, operator3           
x = "\n".join([f"{worker[0]} {worker[4]} {worker[1]} {worker[6]} {worker[2]}{worker[5]} {worker[3]} = " for worker in generate_equation()])                                                                                         
print(x)
```

Comment: Если задача в том, чтобы обеспечить целочисленное деление operand3 на operand4, то разовое добавление 1 к operand3 не решит проблему. Например, 11/5 = 2,2. Добавим единицу - 12/5= 2,4. Здесь можно operand3 формировать из множителей, один из которых - operand4

Comment: Да, истина, как всегда была рядом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
if operand3 % operand4 != 0:
    operand3 += 1
...
```

Comment: Все равно получилось, не так как хотел... Вообщем идея такова, чтобы если не делилось, сделать так чтобы делилось и получалось целое число.

Comment: потому что надо не единицу прибавлять. Если вы точно хотите получить такой operand3, который бы делился на operand4, то вам следует сделать ```operand3 = operand4 * random.randint(1, 100)``` (как пример)

Comment: Да, да, да, спасибо.

Comment: Неправильный ответ :-)

Comment: еретик! если я уберу `!=0` то что изменится?

Comment: логически ничего не изменится, но читать станет труднее.
стоит отметить, что вопрос был отредактирован, изначально в тексте вопроса было сказанно что-то вроде "я хочу сделать проверку, и если operand3 не делится на operand4, то прибавить к нему единицу"

Answer (score 0):

Нужно генерировать пары из частного и делителя, а потом находить делимое.

Comment: естесственно сумма в генерации не должна принимать участия, да?